# How to create a reading app with using UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to create book reader app like Apple Books. I created `ReaderPageViewController` with superclass `UIPageViewController`. Also I have created `ContentViewController` with superclass `UIViewController` this is a model of a book page, inside I added web view to show text and other UI elements. In `ReaderPageViewController` I use this code to show pages:

```swift
var pagesContent: [ContentViewController] = []

for page in result.pagesData {
    let contentVC = ContentViewController()
    contentVC.configure(text: page.textData)
    pagesContent.append(contentVC)
}

if let firstPage = pagesContent.first {
    setViewControllers([firstPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Next I need to create custom animation for turning pages. And that's the problem. In `UIPageViewController` I can choose only 2 types of animation `.scroll` and `.pageCurl`. I started searching on Google for ways to create a custom turning pages animation in `UIPageViewController` but couldn't find any information. I searched more and I need to use `UICollectionViewController` with `UICollectionViewCell` to show text in cells like a pages. Finally I need to use `UICollectionViewController` instead `UIPageViewController` in my `ReaderPageViewController`. Is using `UICollectionViewController` instead `UIPageViewController` the right way to create reader app with custom turning pages animation?

P.S. I want to use several types of animations in my app. Custom page animation and default animation. And if one of these `.pageCurl` animation from `UIPageViewController`, do I need to add `UIPageViewController` to my `ReaderPageViewController` to show the animation?

Comment: Is this also your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198398/how-to-create-different-type-of-animation-in-pageviewcontroller-like-in-apple-bo

Comment: @DonMag I'm having error with updating this question. I deleted it and ask a new one.

Comment: @DonMag I use your advice. But I couldn’t find ways to make custom animation with using `UIPageViewController`

Comment: As I commented on your other (same) question: `UIPageViewController` only supports the built-in "page curl" and "paged scrolling" transitions. If you want to do slide / fade / continuous scroll, you can't use `UIPageViewController` -- you'll need to write your own "page" logic and transition animations. Head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift custom view controller transition`

Comment: @DonMag These are not the same questions. I did what you advised me. And my question was changed. `Head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for swift custom view controller transition`. There are different ways to do it. For example, I can do something like this: `secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom`. But when I have 1000 pages (1000 `ViewControllers`) this will load memory. That's why I'm asking if it would be right to use `UICollectionViewController` in this case? In this case I won't need to make a transition between controllers at all

Comment: @DonMag If I should to use custom animation and default `.pageCurl` in my app. I need to use `UIPageViewController ` and `UICollectionViewController ` in one class and switch between them?

Comment: A `UIPageViewController` uses view controllers, so if you're going to use `UIPageViewController` you're **already** using 1000 view controllers. You have to do some research on how to load and manage child controllers, how to transition between views (probably using `CATransition`), and so on. A `UICollectionView` could give you scrolling, but not the slide/fade transitions you're asking about. Try searching for `swift CATransition examples` ... but you need to ***do the research*** -- look at ***dozens*** of examples / articles / blog posts / etc.